# how to resize a picture programatically and add it to the web site

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi there
I am working with visual web developer and would a) like to know how I could programatcally add a picture to the website, instead of going to Website and then add existing item. The idea I have is to upload the picture using the file upload control but then I want to have it added so that it can be accessed using a gridview.
b)I would also like to know how to size the picture using C# code obviously so that is displayed at the correct size.

best regards
arian

Answer (score 2):

here is a full project with source code to manipulate images, including resize.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/ASPImaging1.aspx

And a sample code only for resize

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/04/02/resizing-images-without-loss-of-quality.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use GetThumbnailImage to easily create a smaller verson of the uploaded image.  The code looks something like (it's free typed without a compiler, so there may be some errors):

```
System.Drawing.Image pic = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(sourceFilename);
System.Drawing.Image thumb = pic.GetThumbnailImage(targetXSize,targetYSize, 
                             new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(this.GetThumbnailImageAbort), 
                             IntPtr.Zero);
thumb.Save(thumbPathName);
```

I believe the Image implements IDisposable, so you need to remember to Dispose of them when you're done.

The abort parameter can be a function that simply does this (can't remember off the top of my head when it gets called):

```
bool GetThumbnailImageAbort() {
   return false;
}
```